# Error while getting the OAuth token from AAD for AppPrincipalId

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-hdinsight, azure-data-lake, service-principal

I am creating HDInsight using Data Lake Store using service principal via Template Deployment(shell script).

While I run the deployment script I got the following error after the initial cluster creation of Spark HDInsight cluster.

Error is :

```
At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details. {
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "InvalidDocumentErrorCode",
        "message": "DeploymentDocument 'AmbariConfiguration_x_x' failed the validation. Error: 'Error while getting access to the datalake storage account hdiclusterdls: Error while getting the OAuth token from AAD for AppPrincipalId xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx, ResourceUri https://management.core.windows.net/, AADTenantId https://login.windows.net/xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx, ClientCertificateThumbprint xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx.'"
      }
    ]
  }
}  Correlation ID: xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx
```

My guess is there is some problem between HDInsight and Data Lake store integration using Service Principal authentication.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The error indicates that the info you gave for your service principal is not valid, which could be for a number of reasons. It would be helpful to have some more info about the steps you took before encountering this error. Could you please share how you created the service principal and certificate? (without disclosing any secret information like passwords or cert contents)